# How to display image in image view inside list adapter using sdcard file path

Tags: android, image

i saved few image into the phone storage and than insert it's path in my sqlite database. but when i retrieve it path is perfect but bitmap always returning null.
i tried many libs like picaso and ImageLoader but not working Please help

```
String path = "/files/"+sArrList.get(position).getImg_path();
File imgFile = new File(path);
Picasso.with(context).load(imgFile).into(holder.imageView2);
```

my path thats return by getImage_path

```
/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.example.geet.easysurvey/files/Pictures/Easysurway/EasySurvay-4d9334ab-0245-4cb2-b7b8-0d4fdac376ba.jpg
```

i also tried

```
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8;
Bitmap takenImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath(),options);
holder.imageView2.setImageBitmap(takenImage);
```

bitmap always return null ; please help

Comment: show me you path. I think you're not taking absolute path. Check if the file exists at your path.

Comment: You need to pass the path of image where it is like this  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/files/"+sArrList.get(position).getImg_path();

Comment: i just debug it and got this path "/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.example.geet.easysurvey/files/Pictures/Easysurway/EasySurvay-4d9334ab-0245-4cb2-b7b8-0d4fdac376ba.jpg"

Comment: @GeetuSharma if your function **getImg_path()** is returning the whole path of a image then why you are declaring '/files/"+sArrList.get(position)' before it ?

Comment: i tried with out prefix but still did not work sir

Comment: It's working for me.. My path is `/storage/emulated/0/Folder/Image/IMG_1447950637150.jpg`. Are you sure file exists at same path? @GeetuSharma

Comment: yes path is correct but don't know what's going wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

Suppose path of your pic is

```
/data/data/hnmn3.mechanic.optimist.popularmovies/app_imageDir/image.jpg
```

than you can use this method

```
path="/data/data/hnmn3.mechanic.optimist.popularmovies/app_imageDir"

public void load() {
    try {
        File f = new File(path, "image.jpg");
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewload);
        img.setImageBitmap(b);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do check if Image exist or not in that path like this :

```
  File file = new File(filePath);
 if(file.exists(){
// convert file to bitmap here 
 }else{
 // something wrong in your path then
 }
```

Comment: yes its always in else condition but i don't know  what's wrong with it even all image  showin in my internal storage

Comment: @GeetuSharma Try this way it will work `String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/com.example.geet.easysurvey/files/Pictures/Easysurway/EasySurvay-4d9334ab-0245-4cb2-b7b8-0d4fdac376ba.jpg";` and if it works just change the name of image according to the position.